# How to wire 3 x 12 V batteries to increase both voltage and amperage?

Tags: batteries

How to wire a battery bank for a voltage of 24 V and a maximum amperage providing 3 batteries of 12 V having respectively 125 Ah, 125 Ah, 120 Ah?

Click below for

[Improvements and Specifications](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/396298/198541)

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to EE.SE.  Can you confirm exactly what type of batteries these are?

Comment: All the batteries are deep cycle AGM batteries.

Comment: Ok.  The disadvantage to including the 120AH battery in the arrangement is that it effectively reduces the capacity of a battery it's placed in series with, although as far as I know, lead acid batteries are the most tolerant type to unmatched arrangements.

Comment: What if I couple 2 sets of  12v x 120AH-125AH in parallels and then put them in series in order to have  a 24v x 120AH - 125AH? Hoping such setting will increase the voltage to 24v and the amperage to 245 AH

Comment: Ummmm...  More likely if you reduce the capacity of one battery in the arrangement, you reduce the capacity of all, assuming they still work, so with that assumption you'd get a 24v, 120AH bank.  Just so you know, AH are not amperage.  They are amp hours, or effective capacity.  It's a measure of how long the battery will run with it's rated output current, which would be measured in amperage, and would be an entirely different number depending on the battery you have.

Comment: Basically it’s not advantageous to lower the capacity by using different size of batteries. I can notice that to successfully put batteries in series  and parallels you need an even number of batteries with the same voltage and amperage in order to pair them.

Comment: What sort of load are you trying to power with the battery bank? How much current at 24V?

Comment: I plan to use an inverter/ charger of 24v x 3000W. I willI plan to upgrade in the future.

Comment: Sell the 120AH battery and make sure you only buy batteries of the same capacity when you expand.

Comment: I plan to use a 3000W inverter/ charger of 24vdc x 120vac. I plan to feed a miner of 1600W. Will probably add a second load when I upgrade the battery bank.

Comment: Then why not use a 12V inverter and put all three batteries in parallel?

Comment: I would consider going to 48V instead of to 12.  Your primary side current at 12V, 3200W would be too silly big.  Also, if you're later going to double the load you should really consider a 48V 3200W inverter.  At 90% efficiency, your current will still be 37A for each load you put on, which will require fairly plump wires(~00 size for a 10f run at 1% loss).  If you use 24V, you need 150A, and at some point you really have to ask yourself, how much copper do I want to own?  If you want to run this setup for substantial periods of time, you may end up needing a lot more batteries.

Comment: If you provide datasheets for the batteries and inverter, we may even be able to tell you roughly how much runtime you will get with a 1600W load.

Comment: If you're using a 2x2 125 AH arrangement and 1 1600W load at 90% inverter efficiency, you'll draw about 75A total.  Each parallel battery will pass 37A, and assuming their AH ratings were the same at 37A, you should get a runtime of about 3.37h out of them, which is pretty good for ups function.  We'll see what the datasheets for your battery say, but the $460 marine AGM deep cycle battery I randomly selected is only rated at 125Ah if you discharge it over 20h, so at 15A.  At a load of 25A, the capacity is only 95.8Ah, so depending on your batteries and the runtime you want...

Comment: I also plan to use some solar panels to feed the batteries instead of home power. Using a 24v system in combination with solar or a small generator seems more economical. I will come with the datasheets for the batteries and inverter.

Comment: Ok.  That's a bit different from a UPS setup.  Especially if you aren't worried about sharing proprietary information, it wouldn't hurt to give us an idea of everything you have pictured in your head.  For solar questions, it helps to know where you are in the world, average weather and lighting conditions, things like nearby mountains that decrease daylight hours.  If you want to run 24/7 with even one unit you may need many more batteries and it may be worth going straight to a 120V arrangement.  In the meantime you could use a smaller setup to experiment.  What happens when power is cut?

Comment: Ok.  Once you have more information, update your question with all of it.

Comment: Ok. Will come with more info

Comment: @KH you have a valid point with using 48V even if used for solar power.  I have a 48V solar system because 48V power supplies are more efficient than 24V.  To improve the efficiency of LED lighting, I went with manufacturing all 48V strips for this reason.  I use four 12V 100W panels but my MPPT has a max input of 70V and in Florida in the summer the voltage from the panels exceeds 70V.  Having to buy 2X the batteries to maintain the minimum required capacity gets a little pricey. I also discovered  solar is only sensible to use where mains power is not available due to cost of batteries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel connection of batteries of the same voltage results in a current capacity of (roughly) the sum of each. Some caution is required if the batteries are not identical in brand, age and capacity as they will have differences in internal resistance and the weaker one won't do its fair share of the work.

The Ah capacity of the parallel combination will be the sum of the individual Ah ratings (subject to the same caution above).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGsaK1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Parallel - series connection arrangements.*

Series connection of batteries will give an output voltage equal to the sum of the individual voltages. The output current will be limited to that of the weakest stage of the battery. The output capacity will also be reduced as shown in Figure 1c. It should be clear from this that for a 24 V battery built of 12 V units that an even number of batteries is required.

Comment: Based on  your schemas,  the figure 1b is more efficient for what  I am looking for.

Comment: With model C wouldn't the two in parallel have an issue with being charged to only half capacity?

Comment: Correct. BAT8 would be the limiting factor for charging as well as discharging. BAT9 and 10 would be half charged. It would be a poor implementation.

Answer (score 4):

With those three batteries, and a requirement of 24 volts, I'd use the two 125 Ah batteries in series, and ignore the 120 Ah. That will give you 125 Ah at 24 volts.

There is no sensible way to use all three 12 volt batteries to produce 24 volts.

**Edit:**
Preferably, all batteries in a bank should be of the same make, type and usage history to ensure that they all share the load equally, and age at the same rate.

If your batteries are all fairly new, I'd put the two 125 Ah in series, and try to get a 120 AH to put in series with the existing 120 Ah.

Comment: What if I get another 12v x 125AH to use with the 12v x 120AH. Is it feasible?